akeneo/pim-community-dev dev-master requires php 8.1.* -> your php version (8.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement
Im trying to set up akeneo pim using docker on my local "mac" and getting below error, appreciate any inputs
Im running below command in terminal:
docker run -u www-data -v $(pwd):/srv/pim -w /srv/pim --rm akeneo/pim-php-dev:master 
php -d memory_limit=4G /usr/local/bin/composer create-project --prefer-dist 
akeneo/pim-community-standard /srv/pim "dev-master@dev"
ERROR:
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires akeneo/pim-community-dev dev-master -> satisfiable by akeneo/pim-community-dev[dev-master].
- akeneo/pim-community-dev dev-master requires php 8.1.* -> your php version (8.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
i do have correct version of php installed on my local, below are the versions.
composer -V
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
Composer version 2.8.3 2024-11-17 13:13:04
PHP version 8.3.13 (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.13_1/bin/php)

of interest is the php version in the docker container
